# C# inheritance constructor child and parent ??

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor

i'm a C++ Programmer,and i'm new in C# i have written a little program to test inheritance so here the source code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Lesson3_Class_inherit_
{
   public class Personne
    {
        public string Name;
        public int Age;
        public Personne() { }
        public Personne(string _Name, int _Age) 
        {
            Name = _Name;
            Age = _Age;
            Console.WriteLine("Constrcut Personne Called\n");

        }
        ~Personne() 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Destruct Personne Called\n");
        }


    };
    class Humain :  Personne 
    {
        public string Langue;
        public Humain(string _Name, int _Age,string _Langue)
        {
        Console.WriteLine("Constrcut Humain Called\n");
         Name = _Name;
         Age = _Age;
         Langue =_Langue;
        }



    };

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Humain H1 = new Humain("majdi", 28, "Deutsch");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The output : Construct Humain Called\
and the construct for the class Personne was not called why !!!
In C++ the parent class constructor is called first !! 
Please help !

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051/calling-base-constructor-in-c-sharp).

Comment: The constructor for `Personne` _was_ called. Just not the constructor you were expecting.

Comment: Just a note: you *very* rarely want to define a destructor in C#. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898733/when-should-i-create-a-destructor

Answer (score 6):

In C# you must explicitly call a parent constructor by using the base keyword.
so Humain would look like

```
class Humain :  Personne 
    {
        public string Langue;
        public Humain(string _Name, int _Age,string _Langue) : base(_Name, _Age)
        {
         Console.WriteLine("Constrcut Humain Called\n");
         Name = _Name;
         Age = _Age;
         Langue =_Langue;
        }



    };
```

Comment: Thanks so much !! normally the parent constructor should be called directly ! like C++ !! i don't know why they have changed this behaviour !

Comment: It allows you to control if it is called or not. It's a good advantage. It also allows you to target a specific constructor.

Comment: You don't say... But I don't regret it and I would never go back to C++. :D

Comment: Is it obligatory in C# to make a default Constructor without parameters ?

Comment: @satyres It isn't required, usually. If you define a parametrized constructor you won't get an implicit parameter-less constructor. I know WPF controls require a parameter-less constructor if you want to use it in XAML and I think WinForm controls require it too.

Comment: When you want to make inheritance ,you have to create a constructor without parameters  !! try to remove the constructor(without param) and it will not work

Comment: @satyres Yes, it will. If the base class has a parameterless constructor (including an implicit one), and the derived class doesn't explicitly call a base constructor, then the compiler adds an implicit call to the parameterless base constructor. If the base class has a parameterised constructor but no parameterless one, it still works - but derived classes have to *explicitly* call a base constructor, because the compiler can't guess what values to pass to the base. IIRC, this is *exactly* how it works in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Because it calls the default constructor. To call the other constructor you need to write:

```
base(_Name, _Age);
```

at the beginning of Humain's constructor.

Comment: This is the right answer. (1) You don't have to explicitly call a base constructor, just as you don't have to in C++, and (2) if you don't, that doesn't mean that no base constructor is called. The behaviour is in fact pretty similar to C++, with some minor syntactic differences :P

Answer (score 1):

```
public Humain(string _Name, int _Age,string _Langue) : base(_Name, _Age)
{
    Lange = _Langue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call the base class constructor this way:

```
class Humain : Personne
{
    public string Langue;
    public Humain(string _Name, int _Age, string _Langue) : base (_Name, _Age)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Constrcut Humain Called\n");
        Name = _Name;
        Age = _Age;
        Langue = _Langue;
    }
}
```

As per your requirement, you can even call the ***default constructor*** instead of ***parametrized constructor*** as well.

```
    public Humain(string _Name, int _Age, string _Langue) : base ()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Constrcut Humain Called\n");
        Name = _Name;
        Age = _Age;
        Langue = _Langue;
    }
```