# Does the object type contain a protected virtual Finalize method?

Tags: c#, .net, finalizer, mscorlib

> C# 6.0 in a Nutshell by Joseph Albahari and Ben Albahari (O’Reilly).
>
> Copyright 2016 Joseph Albahari and Ben Albahari, 978-1-491-92706-9.

states, at pages 100-101, that the object class members are:

```
public class Object
{
    public Object();
    public extern Type GetType();
    public virtual bool Equals (object obj);
    public static bool Equals (object objA, object objB);
    public static bool ReferenceEquals (object objA, object objB);
    public virtual int GetHashCode();
    public virtual string ToString();
    protected virtual void Finalize(); //<-- this one
    protected extern object MemberwiseClone();
}
```

which prompted me to go check if `VS's intellisense` gives me a `Finalize()` method for any reference instance, since I do not remember ever seeing one.

I do not succeed in getting such an object with a `Finalize` member inherited (I am trying to access it inside the function, aware of the fact it is protected).

**I checked `.NET's open source code` and the `object.cs` file does not contain a `Finalize` method.**

What am I missing ? Is this a mistake from the author?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The C# compiler does not allow you to override the Finalize method.
>   Instead, you provide a finalizer by implementing a destructor for your
>   class. A C# destructor automatically calls the destructor of its base
>   class.

You must use `~ClassName()` to implement a [destructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b(v=vs.110).aspx).

`Object.cs` is written in `C#` so it has [`~Object()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/object.cs,111) instead of `Finalize()`.

I suggest that you read this [article](https://ericlippert.com/2015/05/18/when-everything-you-know-is-wrong-part-one/) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4899622/3970411)

From [Eric Lippert](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2425867):

> This feature is confusing, error-prone, and widely misunderstood. It
>   has syntax very familiar to users of C++, but surprisingly different
>   semantics. And in most cases, use of the feature is dangerous,
>   unnecessary, or symptomatic of a bug.
>   Sometimes you need to implement features that are only for experts who
>   are building infrastructure; those features should be clearly marked
>   as dangerous—not invitingly similar to features from other languages.