# c# my destructor isn't being called?

Tags: c#, destructor, finalize

I have this simple code and trying to call the destructor but I can't call it :(

I know that GarbageCollector runs when it's necessary, so I used GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(); but it didn't work either.

Here is my code:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
            Console.WriteLine("{0} / {1} = {2}", 120, 15, calculator.Divide(120, 15)

            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

            Console.WriteLine("Program finishing");                           
        }

  }

class Calculator
    {

        // Constructor
        public Calculator()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Calculator being created");
        }

        // Public Divide method
        public int Divide(int first, int second)
        {
            return first / second;
        }

        // Destructor
        ~Calculator()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Destructor is called");

        }

    }
```

And here is my output:

> Calculator being created
>
> 120 / 15 = 8
>
> Program finishing

What am I doing wrong? Why can't I see "Destructor is called" ?

Comment: That is not true: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/destructors

Comment: Relevant https://stackoverflow.com/q/4898733/1015495

Comment: Finalizers in C# are not guaranteed to run. On my machine with your code (VS 2017, Debug, Any CPU), the finalizer is run and "Destructor is called" gets printed.

Comment: You can understand functionality of GC over here https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1095402/Garbage-Collection-and-Csharp

Comment: The specification formally calls these "destructors". Calling them "finalizers" is common and totally acceptable. The subtle distinction -- that finalizers are usually thought of as nondeterministic and destructors are deterministic -- is one that is completely lost on the C# community, and it would be unwise to assume that C# programmers understand that distinction. I use the terms interchangeably.

Comment: @AndrewPiliser I'm using VS2017, too. I've run it both with debug and without debug

Comment: @EricLippert Very glad you cleared that up! Coming from a C++/Java background I always operated under the subtle distinction you mentioned, but it's far from common sense from my experience — so I eventually gave up! Anyway, next time I get downvoted for using the *destructor* word in C# land, I'm gonna point back to you ;)

Comment: @Eric Lippert: does it really matter whether “C# programmers understand that distinction” when the *specification* already calls them “destructors”, despite they are nondeterministic like a finalizer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The *lifetime* of a *local variable* is the *lifetime of the activation of control within the local variable scope that declares it*. So your local is alive until the end of main. That alone is sufficient to explain why it is not collected, but there are subtleties here that we should explore in more depth.

The lifetime may be *extended* by a variety of mechanisms, including capturing outer variables by a lambda, iterator blocks, asynchronous methods, and so on.

The lifetime is *permitted* to be shortened in cases where the jitter can prove that doing so has no effect on the single-threaded flow of control. (You can use `KeepAlive` to ensure this shortening does not happen in cases where you must avoid it.)

In your case, the runtime is *permitted* to notice that the local is never read from again, mark it as dead early, and thereby orphaning the reference to the object, which would then be collected and finalized. It is not *required* to do so, and apparently, in your case, does not.

As another answer correctly notes: the GC will deliberately suppress this optimization if it detects that a debugger is running, because it is a bad user experience for an object to be collected while you are examining a variable containing a reference to it in the debugger!

Let's consider the implications of my statements about shortened lifetimes, because I think you may not have fully grasped those implications.

- The runtime is permitted to notice that *the ctor never accesses this*.
- The runtime is permitted to notice that *divide never accesses this*.
- The runtime is permitted to notice that therefore *the local is never actually read from and used*
- Therefore *the object is permitted to be never rooted in the GC at any point in its lifetime*.
- Which means that *the garbage collector is permitted to run the finalizer before the constructor*.

The GC and finalizer runs on their own threads, remember; the operating system could suspend the main thread and switch to the gc and finalizer threads at any point, including after the allocator runs but before control passes to the constructor.

Absolutely crazy things are permitted to happen in scenarios like the one you wrote; the finalizer not running is the least of your problems! It is when it *could* run that is scary.

If that fact was not immediately clear to you, then you have no business writing a finalizer. Writing a correct finalizer is one of the hardest things to do in C#. If you are not an expert on all the fine details of the CLR garbage collector semantics, you should not be writing a finalizer.

For more thoughts on how writing a finalizer is difficult, see my series of articles on the subject, which begins here:

https://ericlippert.com/2015/05/18/when-everything-you-know-is-wrong-part-one/

Comment: Honestly, with the modern toolset you should never need to write a finializer at all, *ever*. Anything that would have required a finiazer could be wrapped up in a custom or pre-made `SafeHande` instead. See the article "[IDisposable: What Your Mother Never Told You About Resource Deallocation](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29534/IDisposable-What-Your-Mother-Never-Told-You-About)" for a great guide written by Stephen Cleary on it.

Comment: @EricLippert thanks for your answer. I wasn't writing a code like this of course. In fact, I was trying to understand how GC and finalizer works. I better understand these two with the article in your blog. I will not try to use a finalizer until I become a software engineer at facebook :P :)

Comment: @Uur: I am at present debating whether to remove usages of destructors in the PHP/Hack code at FB, so if you do come here, you might not have a chance to write a destructor. :-)

Comment: "I am at present debating whether to remove usages of destructors in the PHP/Hack code at FB" So... Did they get removed? :) @EricLippert

Comment: @Gabriel: I honestly don't remember.

Answer (score 1):

If you run a program with the debugger attached it changes the behavior of the lifetime of objects.

Without the debugger a object becomes ellagable for collection as soon as the last use of the object has been passed in the code. With the debugger attached the lifetime of all objects get extended to the entire time the object is in scope, this is done so you can view the object in the `Watch` window of the debugger and not have the object collected out from under you.

You must either run your program in release mode without the debugger attached or set `calculator` to `null` before you call `GC.Collect()` to be able to have the object be eligible for garbage collection and have it's finalizer run.

Comment: Though this answer makes the common solecism of conflating objects and the variables that contain references to them, it's basically correct: the GC knows when it is being debugged and deliberately is less aggressive.  Why the downvote?

Comment: @EricLippert I think it was a mass downvoting of all the answers, mine and two others (one now deleted) all got a downvote at the same time.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Well the two others are just wrong.  The better question is why someone has now upvoted one of those objectively incorrect answers.

Comment: @Servy i agree, but i think i got lumped in with them without the person reading what I actually wrote.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain So you think someone read two answers carefully, realized they were wrong, downvoted them, and then downvoted another answer without reading it?  That seems like an odd assumption to make.  I would say it's more plausible that some number of people actually believe those incorrect answers are correct, doesn't know the correct answer, and downvoted  your answer for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend to really on destructors .net

anyway in your case GC don't think your object is garbage at the moment you calling GS because you have **alive link in your stack** calculator which is point to object in heap 
so you can try to modify this code

```
main(){
  DoCalculations();
  //at this point object calculator is garbage (because it was allocated in stack)
  GC.Collect();
}
DoCalculations(){
  Calculator calculator = new Calculator(); // object allocated
  calcualtor.doSomething();  //link alive
}
```

Comment: The GC is allowed to consider a local variable (or any variable for that matter) dead as soon as it can prove that its value will never be read again, even if it's still in scope.  (It's of course not *required* to do this, but it is *allowed* to do this.)

Comment: @Roland Pashinev it worked fine thanks. Even it isn't garbage when the GC.Collect runs, isn't it  garbage at the end of my code?