# garbage collection not working int .net c#

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

I am working with this code as an example:

```
var p = new person("Amir");
var zp = new person("Amiraa");
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

class person
{
    public person(string nName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("New");
        string name = nName;
    }

    ~person()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Garbage collected");
    }
}
```

But the resault on the console only shows "New", not "Garbage collected". so why is the gc not working?

Comment: Bear in mind that a) garbage collection *does* work in .NET and b) it's intended to let you *not have to think about when objects are collected*.

Comment: Destructor in c# are very non deterministic. See this answer from Eric Lippert: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44573392/c-sharp-my-destructor-isnt-being-called

Answer (score 7):

Play around, and you'll notice that your code works as expected in [Release](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxAJwK4wD4AEBMBGAWAChiA3CZAAgAdKBeSmAUwHcankBnAexgAoARAEEwUZAICUAbjIVKAL1oNmbahx79ho5BAiSZRAOIBhAHTHuAG0tMAxgj7TiJ0wHVoCAGLdkABSYwACawAOaesBCWUPLqjgbEuOxcvMQA3sSUmZRYAMxJGnxYeAAMjAByEGBMEhlZ6URZjdl4AJyCZaz6tU3NpTCVTPTlAwaNAL7E3ZQAfmrJ/DUNdVONRW0ChhTAECGDtlY29kyBXUuZE0RjQA==), but not necessarily [Debug](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxAJwK7wCYgNQB8ACATAIwCwAUBQG4TIAEADnQLx0wCmA7o+8gM4B7GAAoARAEEwUZKICUAbmq06ALyasO3Br0EiJU5BAhzF5AOIBhAHQWBAGzvsAxgmEKKlqwHVoCAGICyAAK7DAYsADmfrAQdlAqOm6mFEQ8/EIUAN4UdLl0+ADMabrC+MQADGwAchBg7LI5ednkea35xACcYlVcJo1t7ZUwtews1SOmrQC+FP10AH7a6SINLU1zrWVdoma0wBARo072ji7sGH1ruTPkU0A=).

This is because the variables `p` and `zp` are still in scope at the point that you call `GC.Collect()`. They still refer to the `person` instances.

In Release, the GC will happily collect objects referenced by variables which are still in scope, so long as they are not used again. In Debug, the debugger needs to let you view the contents of all variables which are in scope, so the GC can't collect them.

If you do:

```
var p = new person("Amir");
var zp = new person("Amiraa");

p = null;
zp = null;

GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

You'll see [the output you expect](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aeRpIh), even in Debug. Note that the tiered compilation introduced in .NET 6 affects this, and the above test might not work as expected.

If you introduce a separate method, so the lifetimes of `p` and `zp` are explicitly scoped, you should see the expected behaviour even on [.NET 6 in Debug](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxAJwK7wCYgNQB8ACATAIwCwAUBQCoCmAzggBQCUA3BQOIDCAdFwPYAbQTQDGTNp14B1aAgBi/ZAAUaMDLADm82BEFQAXjWR0W7SuXwAWAAS0GLCgG8KNtzYBuEZDYAONgF4bGBoAdz9jOn4YRgAiAEEwKGRYyXJ3T28bA38gkPDfSOi4xOSICFTzAF8KCiIIk2jnV3d8AGYGqJj8YgAGYIA5CDAaZha3F3SM1uIATjiBsMrx6Z7+mGGaQMHN8wyaiwyAP0LGmLGpiZWMnvnYjm9gCE0t0SERcRoMZcubA6qgA):

```
Test();
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

void Test()
{
    var p = new person("Amir");
    var zp = new person("Amiraa");
}
```

Comment: Hey, Yes I thought about that - but still it is not working, I am not getting the GB. (still console only shows new).

Comment: See the links in my answer - they show the output I describe. If you're seeing something different, then I'm afraid I can't reproduce it. Make sure you can reproduce what you're seeing on a site such as https://sharplab.io or https://dotnetfiddle.net

Comment: The link you send also only write "new" to the console. it does not show the output from the ~(person)

Comment: See the "Release" link. Interestingly the output from the `p = null` seems to have changed...

Comment: Yes I see your point. but for some reason it does not show on .vs 2022

Comment: If memory services, the tiered compilation in .NET 6 gets in the way here, and might be why we're seeing changing results on SharpLab. See my latest edit