# A Case For a C# Finalizer

Tags: c#, destructor, finalizer

This question has to do with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898733/when-should-i-create-a-destructor) and some of the answers, especially the answer from @EricLippert .

I want to encapsulate reading and writing an Informix SE database inside of a C# class.

I want the `OdbcConnection`, `OdbcCommand`, and `OdbcDataReader` to be created when a class method is called, and remain as long as the class instance is active. I am assuming I need a C# finalizer to do this.

I believe that merely instantiating  C# class in a using statement won't dispose what a class method creates. For example, I would need a finalizer in the following to make sure that `m_dbCon` gets cleaned up, when the class leaves the scope of the `using` statement.

Is this correct?

```
class icsDbIo
{
    private OdbcConnection  m_dbCon;
    private OdbcCommand     m_dbCmd;
    private OdbcDataReader  m_dbReader;
    private string          m_queryString;
    private string          m_dsn;

    public OdbcDataReader connectAndReturnDataReader()
    {
        m_dbCon = new OdbcConnection("DSN=bucky");
        .
        .
        .
        return m_dbReader;
    }
```

Comment: A `using` statement will explicitly call `Dispose`, just do that.

Comment: Also, unless you have a good reason, you should probably be `using` the `OdbcConnection` inside the method too. General rule of thumb for database stuff: connect as late as possible, disconnect as soon as possible.

Comment: I see this less as a duplicate and more as a furthering of the original question. I even referenced the first post. I believe I'm asking a different question.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to implement this is not with a finalizer, but by making `icsDbIo` itself `IDisposable` and creating it with a `using` statement. Then put the cleanup code in `Dispose`.

Exiting the `using` block will then clean up everything as you would hope.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Very helpful.