# Searching for some confirmation or guidance on usage of abstract class in Php

Tags: php, inheritance, abstract-class, abstraction

Basically I'm looking for feedback or guidance on something I've created this week at work. The problem was that I had two types of document upload. These types both shared methods like upload, isUploaded, move etc. But, in some instances they both had unique functionality.

So I thought the best approach to handle this would be to create an abstract class which contains the common functionality and 2 separate classes which extend the base abstract class in order to inherit the common functionality.

So I have:

```
abstract class Upload {

 protected $_id;
 protected $_name;
 protected $_dbTable;

 abstract public function create(Filter $filter) {}
 abstract public function update(Filter $filter) {}

 public function __construct($id){
  if(!is_null($id)){
   $class = new get_called_class();
   return new $class($id);
  }
 }

 protected function upload(){
  //Code implemented
 }

 protected function isUploaded(){
  //Code implemented
 }

 protected function move(){
  //Code implemented
 }

}

Class Book_Upload extends Upload {

 $dbTable = 'book';

 public function __construct($id){
  //Database stuff to obtain record information
  //Set protected member variables
  $results = $databaseCall();
  $this->_id = $results['id'];
  $this->_name = $results['name'];
 }

 public function create(Filter $filter) {
  //Code implemented
 }

 public function update(Filter $filter) {
  //Code implemenetd
 }

 //Other unique functions

}

Class Magazine_Upload extends Upload {

 $dbTable = 'magazine';

 Same as Booking_Upload but with additional functionality
 plus abstract methods

}
```

My query is, am I using abstract methods correctly? Have I followed the correct path. Also, I'm not sure I need the construct in the abstract class. What if someone attempts to call $upload = new Upload($id)?

Comment: Oh, the logic above has been re-typed from memory so ignore any syntactical errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any class should provide a single type of functionality (Single Responsibility Principle, example: [Single Responsibility Principle - A hard to see example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829306)).

An upload class must only deal with uploads. Without more code, I smell an over-functional class from your words that tries to accomplish both the upload and document-spesific tasks.

So before going that way, you should define well what these classes will be doing. Are those document-spesific functionalities really related to the actual act of uploading?

Comment: Hmm I see your point battal but my document classes do need to use the upload methods. The document methods create a record based on the uploaded file and provide functionality to get access to the record data on construction.

Comment: Then the `composition` pattern should be the way to go. You can call the upload class from document classes.

Answer (score 0):

You're extending class doesn't call parent::__construct() so the abstract __construct won't make any difference.

You are using abstract classes correctly; they are base classes that are to be built upon by other classes that share common functions and/or will have the same functionality but is implemented differently.

Abstract classes are a base to be built upon that provide common functionality and structure to other classes.